# Render common child component with differing layout components in react-router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, outlet

I have 2 different pages, with different layouts.  However, right in the middle of each layout is a common component.  I want that component to be rendered into both layouts, without losing state as you navigate between pages.

React router 6 provides the [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) component, but this accomplishes the opposite effect - it enables you to render different child components within a common layout component.  I need to do the opposite - render different layout components, with a common child component wedged into the correct place within the DOM.  Take this code for example:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <nav>
        <NavLink to="layout1" activeClassName="active">
          Layout 1
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="layout2" activeClassName="active">
          Layout 2
        </NavLink>
      </nav>

      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/*"
          element={
            <div className="glowing">
              <Outlet />
            </div>
          }
        >
          <Route path="layout1" element={<Layout1Page />} />
          <Route path="layout2" element={<Layout2Page />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const Layout1Page = () => (
  <main className="layout1-page">
    <nav className="left-nav">Some stuff happening on this page</nav>
    {/* Need glowing div to be rendered here */}
    <aside className="right-bar">Stuff 5</aside>
  </main>
);

const Layout2Page = () => (
  <main className="layout2-page">
    <nav className="left-nav">Layout 2 Here</nav>
    {/* Need glowing div to be rendered here */}
  </main>
);
```

#### [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-router-6-forked-3xpmwq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A58%2C15)

I want the `.glowing` div to be rendered into both Layout1Page and Layout2Page, right in the place in the DOM as you can see in the comments.  Its the surrounding layout that differs between the 2 pages.

My usage of the `Outlet` component does what I would like, almost - it renders the `.glowing` div in both pages.  As you navigate between pages, the `.glowing` div is *not* rerendered, as you can tell because the animation is smooth and does not jump as you navigate.  However, its not rendered in the correct place in the DOM, it seems to be tacked on after the Outlet component content is rendered.

How can I organize this, so that a child component is rendered once across 2 routes, into the correct place within the parent component?

Comment: Sandbox link is broken. Also, FWIW I see that you basically have just two layout components that should render a `div` element with `"glowing"` classname and the `Outlet` where the `{/* Need glowing div to be rendered here */}` comment is. Basically yes, your current implementation has it backwards.

Comment: @DrewReese ah sorry about that, codesandbox has gotten weird lately, I updated the sandbox to be public.  Yes what you described is correct, except the critical bit is that I don't want *each* layout component to render the `.glowing` div independently, that means the `.glowing` div is rendered separately for each layout component (and if it were a real component with state, the state would reset, as hinted by the CSS animation).  I want the `.glowing` div to be rendered only once, commonly across the 2 layout components.  Hopefully I explained that well